# AS3 mismatch while accessing object in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, game-engine, removechild

I have encountered quite a challenging one and I'd love to get some support.
Here is the scenario :

The main Game class instances the Level1 Class in charge for spawning enemies through nested For loops and push them to an array.
It then checks for collisions between the Bullet and Enemy and if it find a collision it  calls a method in the Enemy class that removes removeChild and Splice itself from the array.

The thing is it works for the first few enemies, and then it will pick the wrong Enemy to destroy, and stop completely to function.
I tried using indexOf to be sure I am referring to the right object, but to no avail.
I think the Pslice and removeChild are pointing to different objects.

This mess happended when I moved the removeChild and splice  from the Game Class to the Enmy class

Link to the work in progress : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/69hcmzygnkx7h1e/space_shooter.swf

I'd like some help on this one.
Thank you !!!

Main class : Game.AS

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {
        public var _instance : Game;
        public var player:Player;
        public  static var level1:Level1;
        public var bullet:Bullet;
        private var bullets_arr:Array;
        var fire_on : Boolean;
        var fire_counter : int;

        public function Game()
        {

            level1=new Level1(this.stage);
            player = new Player  ;
            addChild(player);
            player.y = 600;
            bullets_arr = [];
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Main);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUpHandler);
        }

        function mouseDownHandler($e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            fire_on = true;
        }

        function mouseUpHandler($e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            fire_on = false;
            fire_counter = 0;
        }

        function fire():void
        {
            bullet = new Bullet  ;
            addChild(bullet);
            bullet.x = player.x;
            bullet.y = player.y - 32;
            bullets_arr.push(bullet);
        }

        public function Main(e: Event):void
        {

            player.x = mouseX;

            if (bullets_arr)
            {
                for (var m:int = 0; m < bullets_arr.length; m++)
                {
                    bullets_arr[m].y -=  20;

                    if(Game.level1.enemies_arr)
                    {   
                        for (var n:int = 0; n < Game.level1.enemies_arr.length; n++)
                        {
                            if (Game.level1.enemies_arr[n].hitTestObject(bullets_arr[m]))
                            {
                                if(bullets_arr[m].parent)
                                {
                                    bullets_arr[m].parent.removeChild(bullets_arr[m]);
                                    bullets_arr.splice(bullets_arr[m],1);
                                    Game.level1.enemies_arr[n].Damage(10, Game.level1.enemies_arr[n]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(fire_on)
            {
                fire_counter++;
                if(fire_counter == 01)
                {
                    fire();
                }
                else if(fire_counter >2)
                {
                    fire_counter =0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Level1.as where the enemies are spawned and pushed to the array.

```
  package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Level1 extends MovieClip
{
    var i:int;
    var j:int;
    var frame :int;
    public var enemy:Enemy;
    public var enemies_arr:Array;

    public function Level1(target:Stage) 
    {
        frame = 0;
        enemies_arr = [];

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (var j:int = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                enemy = new Enemy;
                enemy.x = j*100 + 260;
                enemy.y = i*40 - 150;
                target.addChild(enemy);
                enemies_arr.push(enemy);
                trace(enemy.parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Enemy class Enemy.AS

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip
    {
        var Health : int;

        function Enemy()
        {
            Health =2;
        }
        public function Damage(Damage:int, enemyHit:Enemy)
        {
            Health -= Damage;
            if (Health <1)
            {
                Die(enemyHit);
            }
        }
        private function Die(enemyHit:Enemy)
        {       
            if(enemyHit.parent)
            {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
                Game.level1.enemies_arr.splice(Game.level1.enemies_arr.indexOf(enemyHit,1));
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should traverse both `Game.level1.enemies_arr` and `bullets_arr` backwards. The point is, `splice()` shortens the array, shifts the elements that are in greater positions than the spliced one(s) to lesser indexes, and the loop counter is not automatically adjusted. The error is pretty common, but is often overlooked. Also, with `bullets_arr` you can get out of the array causing a 1009 error if your last bullet out of `bullets_arr` will hit an enemy.

A small nitpick: You are checking for the array's existence within a loop, and for another array's existence once within the enter frame listener. In fact you should either initialize them with at least `new Array()` or `[]` before you add an event listener to the `Main` object, or wherever this is assigned to, or check like `if (!bullets_arr) bullets_arr=new Array();` and leave it at that, so one check of the array's existence will be needed.

```
public function Main(e: Event):void
{
    player.x = mouseX;
    if (!bullets_arr) bullets_arr=new Array();
    if (!Game.level1.enemies_arr) throw new Error('Hey programmer, initialize your arrays!'); 
    // ^ bad practice to throw exceptions in listeners, but if you get one, you've coded something wrongly.
    for (var m:int=bullets_arr.length-1;m>=0;m--) {
        var bm:Bullet=bullets_arr[m]; // TODO fix type
        // the local variable is a cleaner and faster approach
        bm.y-=20;
        for (var n:int=Game.level1.enemies_arr.length-1;n>=0;n--) {
           if (!bm) break; // bullet was destroyed, why checking more enemies vs that?
           if (Game.level1.enemies_arr[n].hitTestObject(bm)) {
              bm.parent.removeChild(bm);
              bullets_arr.splice(m,1); // splice is done by index, not by object
              bm=null; // oops, missed this. The bullet hit something and is now lost
              // so we null the local var, so we can break out the loop.
              Game.level1.enemies_arr[n].Damage(10, Game.level1.enemies_arr[n]);
           }
        }
     }
    // rest of your code follows here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. You gave me  a lot of material to study and I am not sure I understand all of it.  For now if I copy and paste your code it will throw an error  "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Exception."  I deleted the line and it worked but with the same old erratic behaviour.

Comment: would you advice a website to learn all the fundamentals of as3

Comment: Ouch, I've missed one statement. Fixed.

Comment: About a site to learn AS3 - you might do with official AS3 documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html), and if you need general programming tips, probably stay at SO and search for questions if errors arise. Trial and error is the primary key to learn, reading tutorials (there are some sites with AS3 tutorials, you can start say [here](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4-game-programming/topics/160453-how-to-make-flash-games), the topic has some references) and copying them while wrapping your head around base concepts should do.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. Flash seems to not know what is Exception, I replaced it with Error so it wont throw the 1180 error.  And the behavior is still the same.  I really like the way you check for null variables, and how your code is much simpler than my nested for + if loops. I defenetly learnt something, so thank you.

Comment: also, what do you mean by : "// TODO fix type" ?

Comment: I think I need to use 2d arrays, that may be the mistake. I maybe need to access the array through array[][] as I read here : http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2010/01/13/multidimensional-arrays-in-as3/.  The weird thing is i got it working  before I moved the removeChild and Splice to the Enemy class

Comment: Why 2D arrays, if all you have is lists? A list is natively an 1D array. But, if you made it to work in another class, reread the alterations you've made and you'll likely find an omission. About `Exception` - okay, let it be `Error`, my bad. About `TODO fix type` - if your bullet's type is not `Bullet`, you should replace `Bullet` with a proper name.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, it was very stupid of me :
I just mistyped the Die function in the Enemy class :

I have written :splice(Game.level1.enemies_arr.indexOf(enemyHit,1)) instead of splice(Game.level1.enemies_arr.indexOf(enemyHit),1)

Anyway I learnt a lot of think by trying to fix this error.
Thanks